Flutter TabBarView Height Issue Inside NestedScrollView
I'm working on a Flutter application where I have a TabBarView inside a NestedScrollView. However, I'm experiencing an issue where the TabBarView does not have a defined height, causing the tabs to not display their content correctly.
Here's a simplified version of my current implementation:
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final width = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
      iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
    ),
    body: _isLoading
        ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : Column(
            children: [
              // Video player at the top
              _videoKey != null
                  ? AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                      child: YoutubePlayer(
                        controller: _youtubeController,
                        showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                      ),
                    )
                  : const Center(
                      child: Text('No video available', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                    ),
              Expanded(
                child: Consumer<TMDB_Provider>(
                  builder: (context, movieProvider, child) {
                    final mediaType = movieProvider.getMovieDetails?.mediaType;
                    return CustomScrollView(
                      slivers: [
                        SliverToBoxAdapter(
                          child: Container(
                            width: width,
                            child: TabBar(
                              controller: _tabController,
                              isScrollable: true,
                              labelColor: Colors.white,
                              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                              indicatorColor: Colors.red,
                              tabs: mediaType == 'movie'
                                  ? const [
                                      Tab(text: 'MORE LIKE THIS'),
                                      Tab(text: 'TRAILERS & MORE'),
                                    ]
                                  : const [
                                      Tab(text: 'EPISODES'),
                                      Tab(text: 'MORE LIKE THIS'),
                                      Tab(text: 'TRAILERS & MORE'),
                                    ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SliverFillRemaining(
                          child: TabBarView(
                            controller: _tabController,
                            children: mediaType == 'movie'
                                ? const [
                                    TrailersAndMore(),
                                    TrailersAndMore(),
                                  ]
                                : [],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
  );
}

The TabBarView children are not displaying their content correctly because they do not have a defined height. I have tried using different approaches, such as wrapping the TabBarView in a Container with a specified height, but it still doesn't resolve the issue.
I expect the TabBarView to display its content properly, adjusting its height according to the content of each tab.
